# capture all user interactions in a react application centrally

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to capture user interactions in React ex:- click, scroll etc. I am searching for a way where I can capture these events centrally so that I will not have to write code in each of the components inside the application. Is there any listener or something which can capture all these events centrally ?

Comment: Do you use redux or something similar or it's pure React application?

Comment: @PavelKozlov yeah ! redux too.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom middleware for redux and use it logging user actions.
In this case, you'll be able to capture only actions passed through dispatch method.

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

Here's how to apply it to a Redux store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
​
const app = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(
  app,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
)
```

You can read more about middleware by this [link](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#the-final-approach).

Comment: Yeah ! but there are no action defined for clicks, scroll etc. I wanted to know how can I do this without middleware.

Comment: You can call additional action on click. You can also subscribe on scroll and click events through document api.

Comment: Is that possible without modifying existing application ? I do not want to modify existing components code

Comment: You can try to add these listeners e.g. in main container

Comment: That would be great ! As I am new to React, can you point me to some resource for doing that or include that in your answer ?

Comment: You can add document.addEventListener(‘click’, yourActionFunction) to top level container component. It’s a component where you connect redux to component via connect method. Top level one it’ the first that appears when you go in depth through children from the place where you set provider store. <Provider store={store}>.

Answer (score 0):

You can monkeypatch addEventListener (see [this](https://css-tricks.com/capturing-all-events/))

```
// The magic code
var oldAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, eventHandler)
{
  oldAddEventListener.call(this, eventName, function(event) {
      console.log(event);
      eventHandler(event);
  });
};
```

Warning: you have to make sure that you override the addEventListener function before any event is registered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use e.g. [react-idle-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-idle-timer) for this.

Import the component with:

```
import IdleTimer from 'react-idle-timer';
```

and then in your render method add something like this:

```
<><IdleTimer onAction={(e) => console.log('event happened: ', e)} /><YourLayoutComponent /></>
```

you should end up with a similar result when moving and clicking through the page:

[image]